# how to change the pixel values in a rgb image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, pixel

I have a rgb image, I want to change the pixel values greater than (r:175,g:255,b:55) to Nan in matlab, How can I do that. Please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the locations

```
sel = bsxfun( @eq, I, permute( [175, 255, 55], [1 3 2] ) );
```

set to Nan

```
I( sel(:,:,[1 1 1]) ) = NaN;
```

Special care:
Your image `I` should be of floating point type (`double` or `single`) otherwise you will not be able to use `NaN` (`NaN` is defined only for floating point types).  However, it is usually the case that for floating-point images the RGB value ranges between 0 and 1 (and not 255).
So, you might want to compare to `[175 255 55]/255` instead...

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot, I tried using your method, but it only converts few pixels to Nan and not all, My image min and max are 0 & 255 respectively and size of image is 50x68X3. its a png image

Comment: @ankit.1g what is the data type of your image? is it stored as `double`, `single` or `uint8`?

Comment: @ankit.1g how can you assign `NaN` to `uint8`?

Comment: Can I change it to black pixel value?